# How to reduce a store quantity count daily once using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to develop a script, which will reduce a `numeric` value `-3 once a day`, this script is for my store

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var store_count = 952;
    var Date_val  = new Date();

    //Daily once I need to reduce my store_count -3
    if(Date_val == 'Here i have to check the condition for allowing this happen daily once') {
      store_count = store_count-3;
      $('#deducted_store_count').text(store_count);
    }
  });
</script>
<div id="deducted_store_count">952</div>
```

I am not storing this value in Database. Just I want to place this value in a div. As like I mentioned above.

`I don't want to subtract the date as someone has flagged this question for subtraction of date`, my question is different.

if my store count is `952` today, tomorrow it have to reduce to `949` and -3 for a each and every day.

Comment: And where would you store the yesterday value?

Comment: @zerkms i need to reduce the value each and every day once. That is today i need to change, that too only once.

Comment: google: "javascript date reduce"

Comment: @zerkms I just need the code.so that it will be helpful for me to understand

Comment: have you tried to google as I suggested? Why not? PS: "I am a Senior PHP developer" -- this made my day, thank you :-D

Comment: @zerkms Hope which is not a duplicate as like that question

Comment: Its possible if you or your user is not going to reload that page.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'm going to tell you how, then I'm going to question very hard, "Why?"

Here's how:

```
var store_count = 952;

// 24 hours, 60 minutes per hour, 60 seconds per minute, 1000 milliseconds per second
var delay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

window.setInterval(
  function () {
    store_count = store_count - 3;
    $('#deducted_store_count').text(store_count);
  }, delay);
```

So here's my question, what are you thinking you're accomplishing here? Going down three per day, the store count would finally be down to zero after 317 days. How is this program going to run in any browser or Node.js server with an in-memory variable like store_count undisturbed for that length of time without any chance of a power outage or somebody closing down the software?

Data which is slowly going to be decremented or otherwise manipulated over a long period (anything over a few minutes) is usually stored in some kind of long term storage like a database, a file, localStorage in the browser, etc. Something that is persistent and can be guaranteed to still exist if something happens to the environment. But you're asking this question like you think "store_count" is going to be around to celebrate its next birthday.

Are you sure this data shouldn't be in MongoDB or something somewhere?

Comment: P.S. For those who wish to get nit-picky. I'm well aware that setInterval could be off by a few milliseconds, and that slight difference, if it were predominantly faster or slower could eventually add up to enough to throw off the count. But it would take a really really long time and I think this idea has bigger issues.